# Upper bound on the error between a line integral and its Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

Given, a close curve $C$ and a vector field $F$, how can we find a bound, say  $\epsilon$, between the line integral of $F$ and its Riemann approximation with $n$ samples?

$$\vert I(n) - L\vert\le \epsilon$$

where

$$I(n) := \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}F(r(t_i)) \cdot (r(t_i+\delta)-r(t_i))$$

and

$$L := \oint F(r)\cdot dr$$